# Looping alert box is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have written some code so that when I click on a specific div, a JavaScript function will be called to add some data into database. The problem is that the function is in a for loop, so when I click on it a success box will keep re-appearing, when I put the method out of loop, it don't work. This is the code:

```
for (i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
var objSkills = JSON.parse(data);
if (objSkills.skills[i - 1].idemetteur != <?php echo $me; ?>) {
    $("div[class^='plus_']").click(function() {
        var sk = $(this).attr("sk");
        addSkillEndo(sk);
    })
}


}
```

Here are the div examples:

```
<div id="itemskill">
  <div class="skilltext" id="skilltext_1301" value="1301">Bourse</div>
  <div id="counter" class="plus_1301" em="1301" sk="82" style="">+</div>
</div>

<div id="itemskill">
  <div class="skilltext" id="skilltext_1301" value="1301">Finance</div>
  <div id="counter" class="plus_1301" em="1301" sk="83" style="">+</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A side-note but important: __IDs in HTML must be unique.__

Answer (score 0):

If you give your divs an unique ids, you can try to call them like:

```
$("#skilltext_1301").click(function() {
    var sk = $(this).attr("sk");
    addSkillEndo(sk);
});
```

Or try it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div[class^='plus_']").click(function() {
        var sk = $(this).attr("sk");
        addSkillEndo(sk);
    });
});

for (i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
    var objSkills = JSON.parse(data);
    if (objSkills.skills[i - 1].idemetteur != <?php echo $me; ?>) {
        // do anything
    }
}
```

A side-note: change your for loop to:

```
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){}
```

and you can erase "- 1" in your if statement.